# Hash from to string to array, and save to disk with DB_File module

Tags: arrays, database, perl, hash

I have four tab-separated files with millions of lines that look like this

```
WRPPI   smain   hd%ww_mod%oti_obj2%vnw_vc%cp
WRUEA   smain   hd%_mod%_mod%pp_mod%pp_predc%ppart_su%
WSUEA   smain   hd%ww_mod%advp_obj2%vg
WRPPI   smain   hd%ww_mod%bw_mod%np_mod%pp_mod%pp_predm%cp_su%np
WRPPI   ssub    hd%vnw_predc%vz_su%ww
WSUEA   smain   hd%ww_svp%vnw_vc%svan
WSUEA   smain   ld%pp_mod%bw_mod%bw_mod%pp_mod%ww_su%spec
WSUEA   ppart   mod%bw_mod%n_mod%np_obj2%np_su%
```

I want to create a hash of arrays, with a focus on efficient processing and access, that can be saved on disk with the [`DB_File`](http://metacpan.org/module/DB_File) module.

I do not have access to other modules—only to `DB_File` and the default Perl v5.10 modules.

**Edit**: *it seems that the best approaches require additional modules, so I guess I can allow it. I will have to contact our IT guy. So other modules are allowed but please keep it to a minimum.*

The hash keys would be a concatenation of the first two columns, and the corresponding values would be an array of values from the third column. For instance

```
'WRPPIsmain' => [
    'hd%ww_mod%oti_obj2%vnw_vc%cp',
    'hd%ww_mod%bw_mod%np_mod%pp_mod%pp_predm%cp_su%np'
]
```

What I have so far creates a hash with the concatenation as a keys as I want, but a string of tab-separated values for values. But I can imagine that when accessing the hash, this is not efficient at all, especially when that string can be very long when a lot of values are concatenated.

So instead of the expected output above, I have a tab-separated string.

```
'WRPPIsmain' => 'hd%ww_mod%oti_obj2%vnw_vc%cp    hd%ww_mod%bw_mod%np_mod%pp_mod%pp_predm%cp_su%np'
```

This is my code so far

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use DB_File;

# Convert files in directory to DBM file so it
# can be used as a hash.
# COMPONENT.CAT => bfpattern1   bfpattern2  ...

# arg1: directory where overview files are stored

# perl basexcontent2db.pl contents;

tie my %HASH, "DB_File", '/some/path/content.db',
    or die "Cannot open DB_File: $!";

my $path = shift(@ARGV);    # e.g. some/path/
opendir( DIR, $path );

while ( defined( my $file = readdir(DIR) ) ) {

    next if $file =~ /^\.\.?$/;

    print STDERR "\nProcessing $file\n";
    open( FILE, "$path/$file" ) or die "Cannot open file $path/$file";

    my $linenr = 0;

    while (<FILE>) {
        $linenr++;
        print STDERR "$linenr\r";
        chomp;

        my ( $comp, $cat, $bf ) = split(/\t/);
        my $compcat = $comp . $cat;

        if ( $HASH{$compcat} ) {
            $HASH{$compcat} .= "\t$bf";
        }
        else {
            $HASH{$compcat} = $bf;
        }
    }

    close(FILE);
}

closedir(DIR);

untie %HASH;
```

How can I convert this to a hash from string to array without losing the ability to save this to disk as a hash which in turn is accessible for another script?

Please also provide an example of how I would then access all keys for a value.

Preferably I want some easy access such as

```
tie my %BFHASH, "DB_File", '/some/path/scripts/content.db'
    or die "Cannot open database file: $!\n";

my @dbases = $BFHASH{'WRPPIsmain'};
```

Requirements: the processing of the data *to* a hash database (or other) is not important, but the access and information retrieval should be very fast. The database can be accessed multiple times at the same time, but this will not occur too often. Also, once created, the database will never change. SQL is an option, especially if it's performance-wise the best option, but I am not experienced in this field. If your answer includes SQL, please provide details on how to access that database from a Perl script.

**Note**: it seems that in editing by @Borodin, some finer details went missing which may have caused down-voting and the vote to close. After the edit it wasn't clear any more what my current output was, and what I wanted to achieve. I have reinstated that information. I hope then that down-voters will reconsider. I always try to make my posts as clear as possible and put a lot of time in them.

Comment: Replace `.=` with `push`. BTW, neither `.=`, nor `push` needs else branch for previously non-existing value. It will do right thing by itself. Use `MLDBM` module to allow multilevel structures.

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov So, remove if-else, and simply use `push($HASH{$compcat}, $bf)`? And I can then access that array as I proposed at the end?

Comment: Berkeley databases can only store strings; they can't store arbitrary Perl data structures. The typical solution is to use [DBM::Deep](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/DBM-Deep/lib/DBM/Deep.pod); if you really can't use that, then you'll have to serialize your values by hand before storing them.

Comment: Rather `push(@{$HASH{$compcat}}, $bf)`. Newer Perl can handle your syntax, but better not count on it. `MLDBM` will handle transparent serializing/deserealizing, but be sure to check its docs for some peculiarities with tied interface. And also while it is simple, I'm not sure this is most fastest/efficient way. You could roll somewhat more complex solution with better serializing yourself if you agree to abandon "should just work like plain hash" requirement.

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov Hm, you have my attention. If you want you can post an answer without that restriction, but please provide an example how to store and access the database. Als note I removed the restriction concerning modules.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Thank you for the confirmation. It seems that additional modules would greatly simplify things, so I edited my post.

Comment: I think your starting point of using a `DB_File` tied hash is the wrong one. On the face of it a simple `Data::Dumper` string would be better choice than a tied hash. What are your requirements for multiple access? Do you need many scripts to be able to access this data *simultaneously* or do you simply need to store the information to disk for later retrieval? From what I've read I think a simple two-table SQLite database, which can be memory-resident if you wish, would be the best solution. But you've talked far more about your preconceptions than any requirements that you may have

Comment: It seems that in editing, some finer details went missing which may have caused down-voting and the vote to close @Borodin After the edit it wasn't clear any more what my current output was, and what I wanted to achieve. I have reinstated that information. I hope then that downvoters will reconsider. I always try to make my posts as clear as possible.

Comment: @Borodin I read through the documentation of `Data::Dumper` and it isn't clear to me how to use this. Feel free, however to provide an answer that involves this module. If you do not have the time, I understand.

Comment: @BramVanroy: I am, sorry that I misrepresented you. I moved your example of an array to a line of its own, but couldn't make head or tail of what you had written yourself so made my best guess. I also thought an example for *"string of tab-separated values"* was unnecessary as the phrase is self-explanatory, but I agree that it is nicer to have the same data represented in the two alternative ways.

Comment: @BramVanroy: It sounds like all you're asking for is a way to *serialise* your data so that it can be stored and recovered by several different programs. I don't think you're expecting to give multiple programs simultaneous access, is that right? I suggest you take a look at this [**Comparison of Perl serialization modules**](http://blogs.perl.org/users/steven_haryanto/2010/09/comparison-of-perl-serialization-modules.html) and perhaps anything similar that you might find with Google. Note that the article is wrong that `eval` is necessary to read the dumped data. A simple `do` will work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just [`push`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/push.html) onto an array reference, and [autovivificaiton](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) will take care of the rest. [You can't store complex data structures with DB_File](https://metacpan.org/pod/DB_File#How-do-I-store-complex-data-structures-with-DB_File), and since you can't use any other modules for whatever reason, you'll need to create simple string values using the separator of your choice (`,` in this example).

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dump;

my %data;

while (<DATA>) {
    my @fields = split;
    my $key = join('', @fields[0, 1]);
    push(@{$data{$key}}, $fields[2]);
}

for my $value (values(%data)) {
    $value = join(',', @$value);
}

dd(\%data);

__DATA__
WRPPI   smain   hd%ww_mod%oti_obj2%vnw_vc%cp
WRUEA   smain   hd%_mod%_mod%pp_mod%pp_predc%ppart_su%
WSUEA   smain   hd%ww_mod%advp_obj2%vg
WRPPI   smain   hd%ww_mod%bw_mod%np_mod%pp_mod%pp_predm%cp_su%np
WRPPI   ssub    hd%vnw_predc%vz_su%ww
WSUEA   smain   hd%ww_svp%vnw_vc%svan
WSUEA   smain   ld%pp_mod%bw_mod%bw_mod%pp_mod%ww_su%spec
WSUEA   ppart   mod%bw_mod%n_mod%np_obj2%np_su%
```

Output:

```
{
  WRPPIsmain => "hd%ww_mod%oti_obj2%vnw_vc%cp,hd%ww_mod%bw_mod%np_mod%pp_mod%pp_predm%cp_su%np",
  WRPPIssub  => "hd%vnw_predc%vz_su%ww",
  WRUEAsmain => "hd%_mod%_mod%pp_mod%pp_predc%ppart_su%",
  WSUEAppart => "mod%bw_mod%n_mod%np_obj2%np_su%",
  WSUEAsmain => "hd%ww_mod%advp_obj2%vg,hd%ww_svp%vnw_vc%svan,ld%pp_mod%bw_mod%bw_mod%pp_mod%ww_su%spec",
}
```

Comment: This won't work for the OP's use case because Berkeley databases can only store strings; they can't store Perl data structures. There are modules like MLDBM and DBM::Deep to get around that, but the OP supposedly only has access to DB_File.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Perhaps, but wouldn't that be a separate issue? This question specifically asks how to create a hash of arrays.

Comment: The OP said "I want to create a hash of arrays, with a focus on efficient processing and access, *that can be saved on disk with DB_File.*" I don't think this answer addresses that.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Then the question is fundamentally flawed. "I have an apple that I want to turn into apple pie. The only requirement is that I don't have and can't get any flour, sugar, butter, or salt. How can I make an apple pie using only apples?"

Comment: @Matt Jacob, You can explain that's it's not possible, and suggest an alternative, such as `$_ = join(";", @$_) for values %data;`

Comment: I edited my question and removed the restriction on modules. I wasn't aware that it was completely impossible, I just thought it was hard to do. Do note however that the focus is on efficiency.  So any other solution is welcome as well.

Comment: @BramVanroy Then you would just use [MLDBM](https://metacpan.org/pod/MLDBM) as mentioned in the documentation for DB_File.